# Google cloud deployment manager couldn't create deployment using "logging.v2.sink" by Permission Denied

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-deployment-manager

I deployed `logging.v2.sink` using Google Cloud Deployment Manager, however the deployment was failed by permission denied.

The problem was also happened in [this logsink example of Google Cloud Deployment Manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/39563ec2e08a8225adc5d170fbeebf681fe59f67/community/cloud-foundation/templates/logsink).

The result is following:

```
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/my-project-id/resources/sink
  message: 
{   
    "ResourceType": "logging.v2.sink",
    "ResourceErrorCode": "403",
    "ResourceErrorMessage": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The\n    caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "statusMessage": "Forbidden",
        "requestPath": "https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my-project-id/sinks",
        "httpMethod": "POST"   
    }
}
```

The deployment was executed by owner role, moreover I can create logging sink using cli.
`gcloud` installed in local is newest (v217.0.0).

Why does this problem happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I misunderstood permissions of cloud deployment manager.
I noticed that the accounts of deploying template and creating resources are different(https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/access-control).

When I add the Logging Admin role to the service account, deployment succeeds.

`[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. Elaborating the answer above:

Deployment manager uses `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` to create resources on your behalf. You can check the policy binding for this service account:

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT_NUMBER]`

This service account has `roles/editor` on the project by default, which has the following policies for logging sinks:

```
- logging.sinks.get
- logging.sinks.list
```

You can confirm this using this command:
`gcloud iam roles describe roles/editor`

`roles/logging.configWriter` has logging.sinks.{list, create, get, update, delete} permissions, so you can add a new policy binding to your project and then retry:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding secstate-gcp-test02 \
--member serviceAccount:[PROJECT_ID]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/logging.configWriter
```